# c++のmapの使い方について

Tags: c++

[AtCoderの問題](https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc019/tasks/abc019_3) を解くにあたって、mapを使った以下の解法について質問がございます。

#### 質問内容

`map<int, int>` が何と何のペアで結びついてるのかわかりません。mp.firstは入力例3で言うと2,3,5,7だと思ってるのですが、mp.secondって最初はただの空箱という認識で合ってますでしょうか？
また、

2→2で割り切れるから割って1になる→1→まだないから0を返す
3→まだないから1を返す
5→まだないから2を返す
7→まだないから3を返す

で0,1,2,3の合計４が答え、という仕組みかと思ったのですが、`mp[num]=1` が何をしてるのかよくわかりません。よろしくお願い致します。

#### 現状のコード

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    map<int,int> mp;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++ i){
        int num;
        cin >> num;
        while(num%2==0){
            num /= 2;
        }
        mp[num] = 1;
    }
    cout << mp.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 今の書き方だとリンク先が読めないとなかなかご質問の意図が読みづらいので、リンク切れが起こったとしてもある程度はご質問の内容が把握できるような書き方にしていただけるとありがたいです。そうすることで、寿命の長い Q&A を作ることができます。

Comment: 了解です。次回から問題文をきちんと打つようにします。ご指摘いただきありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

挙動は他の方が答えているとおりで正しいのですが、今回の場合、キーに対応する値が常に `1` であり、保存する意味がありません。このような場合は `std::set` を用いるほうが良いです。`std::set<T>` は、`T` 型の（重複しない）値の集合を表します。すでに挿入された値をもう一度挿入すると何も起こりません。

今回のコードの場合、 `map<int,int>` の代わりに `set<int>`、`mp[num] = 1` の代わりに `mp.insert(num)` とすることで書き換えることができます。

Answer (score 1):

これは std::map `mp` を集合のように使っている例です。`mp[num]` の値は何でもよくて、ただ `mp` に `num` が登録されたことを表現するために 1 を代入しています。

この問題では、x、2x、4x、8x、16x、……という系列の数を全て同一視したとき、与えられた N 個の整数は何種類の系列に分けられるか、ということが問われています。ある整数がどの系列にいるかは、その数を 2 で割れるだけ割れば分かります（いずれ系列の最初の数に至ります）。系列の最初の数をその系列の代表元として扱うことで、プログラム上で系列の数を数えやすくしています。

あとは何種類の系列があったかを数えるだけです。今回のプログラムではこのために std::map を使っています。つまり、それぞれの整数を代表元に変換した後、その代表元 `num` について `mp[num] = 1` とすれば、まだ `mp[num]` が定義されていなければ新しく `mp[num] = 1` として定義が追加されますし、既に追加されていればそのまま特に何も変わりません。全部の整数についてこの処理をした後に `mp.size()` を調べれば、最終的に `mp` に定義された数、つまり系列の種類数が分かります。

この上でご質問に答えます。

> mp.secondって最初はただの空箱という認識で合ってますでしょうか？

いいえ、微妙に合っていません。代入するまでは箱自体が存在していません。（また、std::map に対して mp.second() も定義されていません、何となく伝わりますが……）

Comment: mp[num]=1の1ってvalueですよね？ということは入力例3で言うとkey→valueの組が1→1,3→1,5→1,7→1となり、mp.size()でkey→valueのペアの数の4を出力という理解で合ってますでしょうか？

Comment: はい。std::map の size の挙動はドキュメントに書いてあるので、調べてみてください。たとえば和訳されたものですと https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/map/map/size.html などなど。

Comment: 同じvalueが複数あるってありなんですね。mp[num]=1というのがどうしても気持ち悪くて1の部分をmp.size()に変え、for文出てからint ans=mp[num];としcout << ans << endl;したら通りました。同じvalueがあることによって不便になる場面はないのでしょうか？

Comment: 全く無いです。std::map は数学的な関数をデータ構造として表そうとしているといって良いです。ある関数 f について f(1) と f(2) の値が一緒でも何も困らないのと同様に、std::map で同じ値を返り値に格納しても何も困りません。（少し立ち入ると、そうではない、引数が異なれば返り値も異なるような関数を単射と言い、単射性が必要とされる場面はまた別にあります。）　`mp.size()` を入れてしまうと（今回のテストケースには無いでしょうが）オーバーフローが怖くなるのでむしろデメリットがあります。

Comment: そうなのですね。詳しく教えてくださりありがとうございました！